# CUDA thread local array

Tags: cuda

I am writing a CUDA kernel that requires maintaining a small associative array per thread. By small, I mean 8 elements max worst case, and an expected number of entries of two or so; so nothing fancy; just an array of keys and an array of values, and indexing and insertion happens by means of a loop over said arrays.

Now I do this by means of thread local memory; that is  identifier[size]; where size is a compile time constant. Now ive heard that under some circumstances this memory is stored off-chip, and under some circumstances it is stored on-chip. Obviously I want the latter, under all circumstances. I understand that I can accomplish such with a block of shared mem, where I let each thread work on its own private block; but really? I dont want to share anything between threads, and it would be a horrible kludge.

What exactly are the rules for where this memory goes? I cant seem to find any word from nvidia. For the record, I am using CUDA5 and targetting Kepler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are either stored in registers, or (cached for compute capability >=2.0) off-chip memory.

Registers are only used for arrays if all array indices are constant and can be determined at compile time, as the architecture has no means for indexed access to registers at runtime.

In you case the number of keys may be small enough to use registers (and tolerate the increase in register pressure). Unroll all loops over array accesses to allow the compiler to place the keys in registers, and use `cuobjdump -sass` to check it actually does.

If you don't want to spend registers, you can either choose shared memory with a per-thread offset (but check that the additional registers used to hold per-thread indices into shared memory don't outvalue the number of keys you use) as you mentioned, or do nothing and use off-chip "local" memory (really "global" memory with just a different addressing scheme) hoping for the cache to do it's work.

If you hope for the cache to hold the keys and values, and don't use much shared memory, it may be beneficial to select the 48kB cache / 16kB shared memory setting over the default 16kB/48kB split using [`cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gac27b566beee1aa9175373bb9e29b8d1.html#gac27b566beee1aa9175373bb9e29b8d1).

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I am actually in the process of writing a python based CUDA preprocessor; abstracting away the 'shared' array mechanism to get on-chip per thread local arrays is right up that project's alley, so ill likely go with that. Not entirely sure this is my bottleneck and will make my kernel faster, but only one way to find out.

Comment: The best option is clearly to ensure the 8 elements reside in registers. Also a thread local array is a safe alternative as it is likely to be fully cached in L1. I have reservations regarding the use of shared memory for this, I don't anticipate performance benefits over L1 caching, nor will it achieve code simplicity.

Comment: As far as code simplicity goes, the register option seems the least appealing of all, no? Also, I should add that I might want to scale to 30 elements or so; which might actually be feasible with my 255 kepler registers, but still... How do L1 and shared access times compare? If L1 is even comparably fast, thatd be strongly preferred; keeping in mind that of those 30 allocated elements, probably only 3 or 4 are in use at any time. Especially if I interleave the key/value pairs, could I be reading from a single line of L1 cache 99% of the time? If so, I call premature optimization on myself...

Comment: L1 cache and shared memory have the same access time (they are in fact the same memory, that is why the ratio between them is configurable). And there is no need to interleave key/value pairs either: 32 consecutive word-wide accesses from one warp map exactly to one 128 byte cache line. The only thing worth making sure is that all threads in a warp read from the same index into the array of keys at the same time, so that you don't get scattered cache reads per warp.

Comment: I know they are the same memory, but I figured caching logic might have some overhead.

Anyway, turns out this is already clearly not my bottleneck; simplifying my algorithm to completely remove the associative array does not really make a difference in execution times, so supposedly they are happily in cache.

On a more disappointing note; I thought small Kepler also read const __restrict__ ptrs from the read only cache, but it doesnt. That would have saved me so much work...

Comment: In order to go through the constant cache, accesses must also be uniform, and the compiler must be able to deduce it to generate the special `LDU` PTX instruction. Alternatively you could use inline PTX assembly to manually produce that instruction. In any case, the official documentation seems to provide no guarantee that even with `LDU` the read goes through the constant cache, but I believe it does on all CUDA architectures since `LDU` was introduced with compute capability 2.0.